# 401 error while using @react-oauth/google

Tags: javascript, oauth

```
  const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({.            
    flow: 'auth-code',                              
    onSuccess: async (codeResponse) => { 
      const response = await axios.post(              
        'my backend api '
        {
          accessToken: codeResponse.code,  
          oAuthAgency: 2,
        }
      );
      console.log(codeResponse);
    },
    onError: (errorResponse) => console.log(errorResponse),
  });
```

This is `React Oauth2` grammar. I want to do by authorization code flow
sending authorization code to backend for getting access token.

I'm working on this for two days. Please help me.

Comment: Dont do it like that.   Login though the backend then dont send tokens around like that.

Comment: the what shoul i do bro..